# Default permission when mounting usb-drive

Tags: permissions, filesystems, mount

I have an USB-Stick that has two partitions:

1. boot (vfat)
2. rootfs (ext4)

When I plug this stick into my computer the partitions are displayed in the file viewer. (Debian Jessie with Mate). when I click this item the drive will be mounted.

The problem are the access rights of the destination folders.

Partition #1:
I'm the owner and group owner, which is OK

Partition #2:
Owner is root, group is root. Other users have read and execute access.

How could I change this?

Answer (score 1):

`vfat` can be mounted with `-o uid=<uid>,gid=<gid>`, which is what your device daemon is likely doing.  This happens because `vfat` is a filesystem which does not have a user ID or a group ID in the inodes.

`ext4` has UID and GID permissions on the inodes.  Therefore all permissions are part of the filesystem and cannot be changed by mounting it in a different way.  You can use `chown` to change the permission of the files on an `ext4` filesystem to your liking. e.g.

```
chown -R <me>:<stillme_group> /path/to/mount/point
```

Note: If you are using a USB stick with an `ext4` filesystem (or any filesystem with UID and GID info in inodes for the matter) and using that USB stick across different machines, it may be wise to use the same UID and GID numbers for your user and group on all machines.  This is because the inode stores UID and GID info simply as the UID and GID number.